# Symfony 2 cache clearing error

Tags: php, symfony, caching, cache-control

My Symfony 2 website has recently been giving me problems when I try to clear the cache. I type the following command in the terminal:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

And get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
No authentication listener registered for firewall "dev".
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems there's something wrong with your security config, so please check that or add it to the question.

Comment: i check it and i think this block cause problem  dev:
        pattern:  ^/(css|images|js)/ i just remove it and everything is ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the sicurity for the specified firewall, so try this line:

```
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(css|images|js)/
    security: false
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This is my security.yml file:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(css|images|js)/
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            success_handler: Redirectionpages

        logout:      

            success_handler: Redirectionpages
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```